Link to external sd card without using volume id?
As it is rn, any link even to standard folders (say, Download) becomes invalid as soon as cards are swapped.
I'm looking for a solution similar to USB/Linux/Windows drives; a link to the device the sdcard is connected to (/dev/ /mnt/ or /storage/something/), rather than to individual partitions on them, which works on Android 10 and hopefully newer versions as well.

Is your phone rooted?

Yes, it is, but if it can be done without root, better still

I do remember that we had here the question if it is possible to change what you call UUID of an sd-card (actually it is an ID of the formatted file-system if I am not mistaken which means it is related to the partition). I can't find it at the moment but if I remember correctly using a hex editor it was possible to make multiple sd-cards use the same UUID and thus the same mount point. Then your links would work for all SD cards with the same UUID.

Yes, I know that, but that's just a complicated workaround that doesn't really solve the problem and may even create another, in that a system (phone or pc) may think a newly inserted card as being the same previously inserted and use cached content from that one card. I remember my previous phone (huawei, nougat, iirc) had a /mnt/ link to external card (ext_sdcard or something like that). This is what I'm looking for to create.

If you want to change mount point then you will need root permissions. But that is nothing I can help you with. May be one of the other users can help you on that.

Yes, I do have root, just need to know what to do with it lol. Thanks, anyway.
